# Partial view having switches called multiple times

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a main view where I am calling a partial view

```
            <div id="Company_EmployeeSMSNotification_Container" class="emp-notif-containers" style="background-color: #e4e2ff;">
                <!-- Start - Employee SMS Notifications Settings -->
                    @Html.Partial("_CompanyEmployeeNotifChildPartial", Model.EmployeeSMSNotifs)
                <!-- End - Employee SMS Notifications Settings -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="Company_AdminAccountsSMSNotification_Container" class="emp-notif-containers" style="background-color: #f7f7f9;">
                <!-- Start -Admin Account SMS Notifications Settings -->

                @Html.Partial("_CompanyEmployeeNotifChildPartial", Model.AdminSMSNotifs)
                <!-- End - Admin Account SMS Notifications Settings -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following is my child view

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="margin-bottom:17px;">
            <span class="title-switch"><input type="checkbox" name="AB_EmployeeSMS" id="@Model.AppointmentBooked" value="true" class="switch-input" checked="">
            <label for="AB_EmployeeSMS" class="switch-label" style="min-width:auto !important;">@BookIt.Portal.Localization.Resource.cmpEmp_AppointmentBooked_Title</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="AB_EmployeeSMS" value="false">
            </span>
        </div>

     

        <div style="margin-bottom:17px;">
            <div style="display:flex; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <span class="title-switch">@Html.SwitchFor(x => x.NewAppointmentRequest, Model.NewAppointmentRequest, "", new { name = "NAR_" + (Model.DisplayText.Contains("Employee") ? "Employee" : "Admin") + Model.NotificationType })</span>
                <label>@BookIt.Portal.Localization.Resource.cmpEmp_NewAppointmentRequest_Title</label>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom:17px;">
            <div style="display:flex; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <span class="title-switch">@Html.SwitchFor(x => x.NewFormSubmitted, Model.NewFormSubmitted, "", new { name = "NFS_" + (Model.DisplayText.Contains("Employee") ? "Employee" : "Admin") + Model.NotificationType })</span>
                <label>
                    @BookIt.Portal.Localization.Resource.cmp_Appointment_Cancelled_Title
                </label>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom:17px;">
            <div style="display:flex; padding-bottom: 2px;">
                <span class="title-switch">@Html.SwitchFor(x => x.ClientArrived, Model.ClientArrived, "", new { name = "CA_" + (Model.DisplayText.Contains("Employee") ? "Employee" : "Admin") + Model.NotificationType })</span>
                <label>
                    @BookIt.Portal.Localization.Resource.cmpEmp_ClientArrived
                </label>
                @if (Model.NotificationType == BookIt.Portal.Enums.NotificationTypes.Email)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following is how I have view Models built

```
  public class CompanyEmployeeNotificationsViewModel
    {
        public CompanyEmployeeNotificationsViewModel()
        {

            // Initialize lists to avoid null reference exceptions
            EmployeeSMSNotifs = new EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel();
            AdminSMSNotifs = new EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel();
            
        }
        public long? UserId { get; set; }
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel EmployeeSMSNotifs { get; set; }

        public EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel AdminSMSNotifs { get; set; }

    }
```

and the EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel as follows:

```
 public class EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel
    {
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }

        public string DisplayDescription { get; set; }
        public Enums.NotificationTypes NotificationType { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_AppointmentBooked_Title")]
        public bool AppointmentBooked { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_AppointmentRescheduled_Title")]
        public bool AppointmentRescheduled { get; set; }

        public string AppointmentRescheduledType { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_NewAppointmentRequest_Title")]
        public bool NewAppointmentRequest { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_NewFormSubmitted")]
        public bool NewFormSubmitted { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_ApptCancelled")]
        public bool AppointmentCancelled { get; set; }

        public string AppointmentCancelledType { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Resource), Name = "cmpEmp_ClientArrived")]
        public bool ClientArrived { get; set; }



    }
```

When I am saving, its not showing the correct toggle (true/false). Can you guys suggest a better way to do it and help me fix toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using the following approach with the help of chatgpt. Posting for others to benefit.

Created a Helper Method in the Main View:

```
@model CompanyEmployeeNotificationsViewModel

@functions {
    MvcHtmlString RenderPartialForProperty<TModel, TProperty>(
        TModel model, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        string propertyName)
    {
        var partialModel = propertyExpression.Compile()(model);
        return Html.Partial("_YourPartial", partialModel, new ViewDataDictionary { { "PropertyName", propertyName } });
    }
}
```

Used the Helper Method to Render Partial Views:

```
@model CompanyEmployeeNotificationsViewModel

@{
    var propertyNameEmployeeEmail = nameof(Model.EmployeeEmailNotifs);
    var propertyNameEmployeeSMS = nameof(Model.EmployeeSMSNotifs);
    var propertyNameAdminEmail = nameof(Model.AdminEmailNotifs);
    var propertyNameAdminSMS = nameof(Model.AdminSMSNotifs);
}

@RenderPartialForProperty(Model, m => m.EmployeeEmailNotifs, propertyNameEmployeeEmail)
@RenderPartialForProperty(Model, m => m.EmployeeSMSNotifs, propertyNameEmployeeSMS)
@RenderPartialForProperty(Model, m => m.AdminEmailNotifs, propertyNameAdminEmail)
@RenderPartialForProperty(Model, m => m.AdminSMSNotifs, propertyNameAdminSMS)
```

Retrieved Property Name in Partial Viewdirectly from the ViewData:

```
@model EmployeeNotificationSettingsViewModel

@{
    // Get the property name dynamically
    string propertyName = ViewData["PropertyName"] as string;
}

<div>
    Model Property Name: @propertyName
    <!-- Rest of your partial view content -->
</div>
```